# Is there a built in name/value pair attribute?

Tags: .net, attributes

Is there a built in attribute in the .net framework to mark up code with an arbitrary key and value? I've had a look through [the list](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.attribute.aspx), but can't see anything useful there. What we ideally want is to be able to say

```
[NameValuePair("MyKey", "My long bit of text")]
```

...and then pull it out later on

Actually, what we really want to be able to do is embed extra info into the assemblyinfo at continuous integration build time, like

```
[Assembly: NameValuePair("MyKey", "My long bit of text")]
```

and then pull it out later on

I've seen Jeff's post about [Custom AssemblyInfo Attributes](http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/archives/000142.html), and it is good, but if there's an implicit attribute baked into the framework it'll be even better.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There is not a built-in attribute that represents a name/value pair, although it would be fairly easy to implement. If your key and value are always strings, you simply need an attribute that takes both strings as constructor parameters.

```
[AttributeUsage(AttributeTargets.Assembly)] 
public KeyValuePairAttribute : Attribute
{
   private string key;
   private string value;

   private KeyValuePairAttribute() { }

   public KeyValuePairAttribute(string key, string value)
   {
      this.key = key;
      this.value = value;
   }
}
```

Comment: Yep, true that. We'd have to make sure the class exists in each "thing" we're building via continuous integration (which could be a world of pain!) but it's a good fallback

Comment: The simplest approach if you want to include the actual source file in each project is to include it as a linked file. The other option is to compile it in a separate DLL (or project) and then include that DLL (or project) as a reference in each of the other projects. Both ways result in only having a single source code file to maintain.

Comment: I like the linked file idea. Not that there's much source to maintain there though :-)